# Is it possible to replace the following two SQL selects with just one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please, observe:

```
DECLARE @UseFastLane BIT


SELECT TOP 1 @UseFastLane = 1
FROM   BackgroundJobService
WHERE  IsFastLane = 1;


SELECT TOP 1 bjs.HostName    AllocatedAgentHostName,
             bjs.ServiceName AllocatedAgentServiceName,
             bjs.IsFastLane,
             SUM(CASE
                   WHEN bjw.WorkStatusTypeId IN ( 2, 3, 4, 10 ) THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END)        AS InProgress
FROM   BackgroundJobService bjs
       LEFT JOIN BackgroundJobWork bjw
         ON bjw.AllocatedAgentHostName = bjs.HostName
            AND bjw.AllocatedAgentServiceName = bjs.ServiceName
WHERE  bjs.AgentStatusTypeId = 2
       AND bjs.IsFastLane = COALESCE(@UseFastLane, 0)
GROUP  BY bjs.HostName,
          bjs.ServiceName,
          bjs.IsFastLane
ORDER  BY IsFastLane DESC,
          InProgress
```

I am using two SQL select statements here. Is it possible to use just one top level SQL select statement, nesting another one within?

Comment: You can use `subquery`, as you are only using variable in `COALESCE(@UseFastLane, 0)`

Comment: Does the first query actually *do* anything?  Looks like it just sets `@UseFastLane` to 1.  ... Hmm, I guess it *could* be acting as a form of `EXISTS(..)`, is that right?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Where there are no rows with the IsFastLane flag, it leaves the @UseFastLane equal to `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the text `AND bjs.IsFastLane = COALESCE(@UseFastLane, 0)` with this:

```
AND bjs.IsFastLane = (SELECT Max(IsFastLane)
FROM   BackgroundJobService)
```

which should give you an equivalent query assuming that there are rows in the BackgroundJobService.

If there might be zero rows in BackgroundJobService then you can wrap the select with a COALESCE function to return 0, like this:

```
COALESCE((SELECT Max(IsFastLane) FROM BackgroundJobService), 0)
```

Comment: I used `COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM BackgroundJobService WHERE IsFastLane = 1), 0)`. Other than that it works.